Justify if there exist a differentiable function f such that $|f(x)|<2$ and $f(x)f'(x)\geq \sin(x)$
The problem states: Justify if there exist a differentiable function f such that $|f(x)|<2$ and $f(x)f'(x)\geq \sin(x)$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$. What I got by another question I made about a related result:
$f(x)f'(x)=(\frac 12f(x)^2)'$ so
$(\frac 12f(x)^2)'=\sin(x)+c(x)\implies \frac 12f(x)^2=C(x)-\cos(x)$ now, $|f|<2$ so $\sqrt{f(x)^2}<2$ or equivalently $\frac{f(x)^2}{2}<2$.
Putting this result on the above equations gives $C(x)<2+\cos(x)$. In other words, we got a function that has to be lower than 1 in some points like $x=\pi$, but, at the same time $C(x)-\cos(x)\geq 0$ so $C(x)\geq \cos(x)$. Finishing my reasoning, we are looking for an increasing function $C(x)$ such that $C(0)\geq1$ and $C(\pi)<1$ which is impossible. Is this right?

Yes, it looks fine to me.

Your proof is correct if you add that $c(x) \ge 0$, so that $C(x) = \int_0^x c(t) \, dt$ is an increasing function for $x \ge 0$.
If would argue as follows, without using the auxiliary functions $c(x)$ and $C(x)$. It is the same idea as in your proof, just written more concisely.
If $f$ is such a function then
$$
 2 = \cos(0) - \cos(\pi) = \int_0^\pi \sin(x) \, dx \le \int_0^\pi f(x) f'(x) \, dx \\
= \frac 12 \bigl(f(\pi)^2 - f(0)^2 \bigr) \le \frac 12 f(\pi)^2 < \frac 12 \cdot 2^2 = 2
$$
is a contradiction.
The proof shows that no function with those properties exists on the domain $[0, \pi]$, or on any domain $[2k \pi, (2k+1)\pi]$ with $k \in \Bbb Z$.

@Martin_R A really nice approach, thank you for your effort and comprehensive writing.

What if $f(x) = 2 \sin(\frac{x}{2})$?
For that function: $f'(x) = \cos(\frac{x}{2})$
So: $|f(x)| \le 2$ and $f(x)f'(x) = \sin(2 \cdot \frac{x}{2}) = \sin(x)$, which means that $f(x)f'(x) \le \sin(x)$.

The problem then is that $|f(\pi)|=2$ which contradicts $|f(x)|<2$

@MiguelCG: you're right. My mistake: I had read $\le 2$ instead of $< 2$.

Nicely seen anyway
